# Using MYSQL Distinct with Count?

Tags: mysql, count, distinct

I'm looking to use both DISTINCT and COUNT in a MySQL query, something like this:

```
SELECT DISTINCT `data1` AS new_data, COUNT(new_data) FROM table_name WHERE `data2`='$data2' AND `data3` = '$data3'
```

The goal being to loop through the DISTINCT results and do something with both the result itself, as well as the COUNT for that result.

Unfortunately, I'm not too great with MySQL...

1. I'm not sure if it can be done this way
2. Is there any other approach that I could use to calculate this all directly in MySQL without multiple DB calls?

Comment: Are you looking for something like a group - as in count within a group

Comment: Yes, group was what I needed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume you want to have a `count` per `data1` where rows match your conditions. Right?
Group by data1 and you're done:

```
SELECT `data1`, COUNT(*) 
FROM table_name 
WHERE `data2` = '$data2' AND `data3` = '$data3'
GROUP BY `data1`
```

Comment: If I did not get your question right then please provide some example data and the resultset you're expecting.

Comment: thanks dude! yes this is exactly what I needed, it's working great in my web app :)

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure to understand your question...

Do you want to do something like:

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT `data1`) AS new_data FROM table_name
WHERE `data2`='$data2' AND `data3` = '$data3'
```

Comment: I was trying something like this initially, but I needed to count the total of the DISTINCT value, plus grab the value itself.